# HelloFX.java:1: error: package javafx.application.Application does not exist

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

```
OS: Raspbian
CPU: RPi (armv7l)
JDK: Zulu11.31+16 (build 11.0.3+7)
JavaFX: self-built https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/archive/jdk-11+7.tar.gz

Problem:
$ export PATH_TO_FX=/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-armv6hf-11-0-7-b1/lib
$ ls $PATH_TO_FX
javafx.base.jar
javafx.controls.jar
javafx.fxml.jar
javafx.graphics.jar
javafx.media.jar
javafx-swt.jar
javafx.web.jar
<bunch of lib*.so>
$ jar -t --file $PATH_TO_FX/javafx.graphics.jar | grep Application
javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.class
$ export MODULES=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openjfx/samples/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx HelloFX.java
$ javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules $MODULES HelloFX.java
HelloFX.java:1: error: package javafx.application.Application does not exist
import javafx.application.Application
```

I've checked and double-checked $PATH_TO_FX, and $MODULES, they are seem to be correct. If i run javac with -verbose, than I see jdk modules loaded, but jfx are not.

Update, 2020.12.19:
Turned out the problem was my build of JavaFX SDK. For whatever reason Gradle
generated module jars with module name as the root folder. Once I stripped
module names and repacked jars SDK works fine. Looking into Gradle issue now.